# Slack Bolt Verification with Oauth

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I've been trying to work through this for a couple of days now. I have a slack app working in development using Slack/Bolt and the built in Express Server. In development, I can successfully go through the installation process, which upon completion, returns the user credentials (auth token, teamId, etc.) and redirects me to my success page. Additionally, my slash commands work as expected.

In production, however, neither the slash command nor the installation process work. The slash command returns a "dispatch_failed" error in Slack and the following verification error in my logs:

[image: error in server logs]

The installation process in development starts with my landing page with a add to slack button which takes me to the slack page where I authorize the required scopes. Submitting this form is where my app times out with the a 503 error. I can see the "code" in the URL but it's not being processed. Before tearing the app apart to try a different authentication method, I was hoping someone could identify where I've gone wrong.

Of importance is the auth token. In development, I declare my xbot token when declaring app. I remove it for production and pass in bot tokens from the context variable in event listeners (slash command, etc.). This is how I understood the process from documentation but could be wrong...

```js
const { App, ExpressReceiver } = require('@slack/bolt');
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env' })
const axios = require('axios')
const request = require('request')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const firebase = require("firebase");

//database config here (removed to de-clutter)

const fetchTeam = async (teamId) => {
    try {
        const ref = await database.ref('workspaces')
        ref.orderByChild('team_id').equalTo(teamId).once('value', function (snapshot) {
            return snapshot.val()
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

// Create a Bolt Receiver
const receiver = new ExpressReceiver({ signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET });

const app = new App({
    signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
    clientId: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    stateSecret: process.env.STATE_SECRET,
    scopes: ['chat:write', 'chat:write:bot', 'im:write', 'commands', 'incoming-webhook', 'users:read', 'users:read.email'],
    // scopes: ['chat:write', 'chat:write:bot', 'channels:history', 'groups:history', 'im:history', 'commands', 'incoming-webhook', 'users:read', 'users:read.email'],
    installationStore: {
        storeInstallation: async (installation) => {
            return await database.ref('workspaces').push({ team_id: installation.team.id, installation })
        },
        fetchInstallation: async (InstallQuery) => {
            return await fetchTeam(InstallationQuery.teamId)
        },
    },
    //removed token for production
    //token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
    receiver
});

//a bunch of stuff my slack app does here (removed)


receiver.router.get('/slack/oauth_redirect', async (req, res) => {
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access?code='
            + req.query.code +
            '&client_id=' + process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID +
            '&client_secret=' + process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
        method: 'GET'
    }
    request(options, async (error, response, body) => {
        var JSONresponse = JSON.parse(body)
        if (!JSONresponse.ok) {
            res.status(500).send("Error: ", JSONresponse)
        } else {
            const newOBJ = {
                team_id: JSONresponse.team.id,
                ...JSONresponse
            }
            console.log(newOBJ);
            await database.ref('workspaces').push(newOBJ)
          
        }
    })
})


receiver.router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const payload = JSON.parse(req.body.payload)
    res.send(req.data);
});

receiver.router.post('/slack/events', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.data);
});

receiver.router.post('/actions', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.data);
});

// Listen for a slash command invocation
app.command('/commandName', async ({ command, ack, say, context }) => {
    await ack();
    try {
        // Call the users.info method using the built-in WebClient
        const result = await app.client.users.info({
            token: context.botToken,
            //in development i use the code below
            // token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
            user: user
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    await say({
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "section",
                "text": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": `Hi there ,! Here are some ways you can use Slack to get things done with Webstacks:`,
                    "emoji": true
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "actions",
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "type": "button",
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Raise a Request"
                        },
                        "value": "create_request",
                        "action_id": "create_request"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "button",
                        "text": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Leave a Review",
                        },
                        "url": "https://kittycats.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    })
});

(async () => {
    // Start your app
    await app.start(process.env.PORT || 3000);

    console.log('⚡️ Bolt app is running!');
})();
```

Comment: When does ```storeInstallation``` gets called? Why do we need '/slack/oauth_redirect if storeInstallation can do this for us?

Comment: @SagarRanglani storeInstallation only gets called after a few things happen.

1. You click on "add to slack button"
2. You see OAuth page, which says "App is requesting permission to access the <demo> Slack workspace. Click green "Allow" button.
3. Next, you should see "Success! Redirecting" and a "Open Slack?" alert on your browser. Click on "Open Slack"
4. Only after you've successfully opened Slack, and you reach your app messages tab, will the "storeInstallation" function actually get called. Hope this helps!

Comment: @HoreaPorutiu do we need to set any event url or some other configuration rather than code?
Because storeInstallation is not being triggered with the same code above in my case.

Answer (score 1):

double-check your environment vars ! :)
I'd overlooked clientSecret having input signingSecret